# specify null value for F# Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

is it possible to specify a customised value to represent null or NaN when loading csv into Deedle data structure? in Python pandas, this is a configurable list option.

Often the input data from csv will contain some arbitrary value to represent null while the rest of the column do have valid value (double type). Currently i have to load them all in then apply a function to the column to tryparse double.

thanks
casbby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported, but I agree that it would be very useful! I created a [GitHub issue to track this](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/issues/231).

We'll definitely add this at some point, but if you wanted to contribute and add support for specifying custom missing values, this is actually quite easy. Deedle uses CSV parser from F# Data, which already supports this functionality and so you really just need to add an additional optional parameter rather than using the default missing values [here in the source code](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/FrameExtensions.fs#L95) (and in other overloads). (And add some test to make sure we don't break this :-))

A contribution would be absolutely awesome!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will take a look the source code and give it my best crack. And thank you guys for deedle.